No .dll file in exported FMU model from OpenModelica
Hello everyone (forgive me if it is a trivial issue, i am new to FMU),
I am currently working on Co-simulation using FMU models. I would like to export an OpenModelica file in FMU file and co-simulate it with a Simulink Model that is also a FMU  file.
However, when i try to run my co-simulation, i get the following message : Error:Error in supplied FMU: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\Users\Léo nicolle\OneDrive\Bureau\IMT Mines Ales\Mission R&D\Modele_Commande_Moteur_CC_fmu55\slprj_fmu\95fff6f236f38c45451bf5be6e80e1a6\MoteurCC\binaries\win64\MoteurCC.dll': specified module could not be found. For more information, see the FMU troubleshooting documentation.
I understood that Simulink could not find the file 'MoteurCC.dll' and after looking in the FMU, i found that there is no .dll file !
I made some research on the OpenModelica website and through the example 'BouncingBall.fmu' exportation, a .dll file appears in their exported file.
Can you please help me ?
Best regards,
Leo
I tried to export my OpenModelica file to FMU file but there is no .dll file in it so i think it can not be runned on Simulink.

Try a directory that isn't OneDrive or contains special characters. If that doesn't help it's probably related to https://github.com/OpenModelica/OpenModelica/issues/12065.
If you think it's not related to that you can also open a new issue on our GitHub https://github.com/OpenModelica/OpenModelica/issues
to tell us how to reproduce your error.

What AnHeuermann is saying is to go to OMEdit->Tools->Options->General and select a working directory such as C:\temp because your user has an é in it. Then restart OMEdit.

Thank you for your responses.However, even when i move the file to a folder where there is no 'é' or OneDrive, i still get the same issue on Simulink and after looking in the new folder, there is still not .dll file...

Are you using OMEdit or command line with scripts? If you use OMEdit you need to change the working directory, not where the .mo file is, that doesn't help. The FMU files are generated in the working directory.

I am using OMEdit and yes i have changed the working repertory with no special caracter  and it still does not work

This problem I had meet before.
Here is the step how I solve it.

check the exist compiler in your computer.
Option-> Simulation-> C compiler etc.


check the FMI platform is suitable.
Option-> FMI-> Platforms



I hope it helps you!
